# Perl Process can't find command svn when called from Java

Tags: java, windows, perl, svn

I need to automatically execute some perl scripts from Java. I use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec` to start the perl process. I generate a start-parameter-string and pass it as an argument to exec. The String looks somewhat like this:

`cmd /C start /wait perl "path\to\perl\script" -p1 scriptparameter1 -p2 scriptparameter2`

I also tried

`perl "path\to\perl\script" -p1 scriptparameter1 -p2 scriptparameter2`.

If I copy that String and execute it via Windows+R everything works, but via exec the Perl-scripts can't find the svn-command. Why does it make a difference if I execute the perl process from java instead of directly from windows?

Comment: Can you run the command `svn --version` from java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. The reason was that I had just installed svn and the PATH envirment variable took effect for cmd but not for other processes (for whatevery reason). After a computer restart everything works as expected.

Comment: Each process has its own environment (which is inherited from its parent). Changes in one process's environment has no effect on the environment of other processes. Windows does have a mechanism for notifying processes of changes to the initial environment, but it's up to each app to listen and handle these notifications.